# How to I test a react component with Jest that maps over an array of objects to match an object value that sets a value to be rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

Below is the component I need to test. Sorry, its seems simple, but I'm new to React and Javascript.

```
import React from 'react';

export default ({ comments }) => {
  const renderedComments = comments.map(comment => {
    let content;

    if (comment.status === 'approved') {
      content = comment.content;
    }

    if (comment.status === 'pending') {
      content = 'This comment is awaiting moderation';
    }

    if (comment.status === 'rejected') {
      content = 'This comment has been rejected';
    }

    return <li key={comment.id}>{content}</li>;
  });

  return <div><h4>Reviewer Comments</h4><ul>{renderedComments}</ul></div>;
};
```

Comment: You could write the test like in the following [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-conditional-render-test-vvun8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jest to test components, we have a few options. I personally recomment [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) as a great starting point.

Since this component doesn't have any interactions, we don't have to worry about that.

First, let's look at the scenarios that we may want to test:

- Does it render an empty list?
- Does it render a single X comment

  - Approved
  - Pending
  - Rejected
- Does it render multiple comments (one more complex test case)

Next, what is our preferred method of testing? I'm a fan of inline snapshots, but not everyone is so I'll give an example of both.

### With [Inline Snapshots](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing#inline-snapshots)

*Note: you need [prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html) in your dependencies to use inline snapshots*

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Comments from "./Comments";

describe("Comments", () => {
  it("should render a single approved comment", () => {
    render(
      <Comments
        comments={[
          {
            id: 0,
            content:
              "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
            status: "approved",
          },
        ]}
      />
    );

    // https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing#inline-snapshots
    expect(screen.getByRole("list")).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
      <ul>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </li>
      </ul>
    `);
  });
});
```

### With [React Testing Library Matchers](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#custom-matchers)

*Note: to get the jest matchers used, you can follow the instructions in the [jest-dom README](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom)*

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Comments from "./Comments";

describe("Comments", () => {
  it("should render a single approved comment - matchers", () => {
    render(
      <Comments
        comments={[
          {
            id: 0,
            content:
              "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
            status: "approved",
          },
        ]}
      />
    );

    // https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohavetextcontent
    expect(screen.getByRole("list")).toHaveTextContent(/Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet/);
  });
});
```

*More examples on this [repl.it example](https://repl.it/@dcwither/TestingComments#src/Comments.test.js)*

You may have noted I used [`getByRole`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries/#byrole), this is the preferred method to use when possible since it uses the [accessible roles defined in W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#docconformance), acting as a bonus test for accessibility.

You can get more recommendations on how to use React Testing Library from [Common mistakes with React Testing Library](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library/).

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the link to the Common mistakes with React Testing Library as well as pointing out getByRole.